# Cassandra Connection Session.execute blocks infinitely

Tags: java, cassandra, driver

i want to connect to my local cassandra DB with the following code:

```
public class StartDriver {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Cluster cluster = null;
    try {
        cluster = Cluster.builder() // (1)
                .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").withPort(9042).build();
        SocketOptions socketOptions = cluster.getConfiguration().getSocketOptions();
        socketOptions.setConnectTimeoutMillis(1000);

        System.out.println("Connection established");
        Session session = cluster.connect(); // (2)
        System.out.println(session.getState().getConnectedHosts());
        System.out.println("Try to execute Query");
        ResultSet rs = session.execute("SELECT * FROM htw.student");
        System.out.println("Query executed");// (3)
        Row row = rs.one();

    //  System.out.println(row.getString("release_version"));
        if (cluster != null) cluster.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

The connection could be established  but at session.execute() the programm hangs forever without any error message. I use the Cassandra 3.8.0 under windows. Connection via cqlsh and devCenter is possible and works great. Can anybody help? Is there any configuration in cassandra.yaml i need to alter?

The output i get is the following:

```
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Connection established
[/127.0.0.1:9042]
Try to execute Query
```

Comment: did you close the connection?

Comment: In code the part were the connection will be closed is never reached and while testing restarted cassandra a few times.

Comment: please show me the exception. And clear the question.

Comment: The Problem is there is no exception in eclipse. The programm execution hangs at "session.execute()".

Comment: Do me a favour. Execute this statement instead of your statement and show me your result.    "SELECT count(*) FROM htw.student ;"

Comment: I did and it is same like before. It seems that the statement never will be executed.

Comment: Do you get all the data from table? Did you add this line ?    System.out.println(row.getLong("count"));

Comment: how big is the table htw.student? is it for testing purposes? running select * or select count(*) it's a very costly operation

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that in the classpath were some lib's like guava which are used from [cassandra-driver-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core). I converted the projekt to maven projekt and from this point the lib's seems to hinder each other. I deletet the lib' from libs folder and only use the maven depnendencies and not its wirking like a charme.